# C++ как получать инфу с нужной строки из txt файла

Tags: c++

Всё просто мне нужно выудить инфу с определённой строки файла допустим на 1 строке написанно 5 а на 2 написанно 10 и как мне запихнуть инфу о числе 10 со 2 строички в переменную string

Comment: 1. читаете файл построчно. 2. на нужных строках производите нужные действия. 3. … 4. profit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Использовать функции семейства *seek. Если используете старый, сишный способ чтения файлов (fopen, 'fread`), тогда используйте функцию fseek. Эта функция получает три параметра - первый - файловый дескриптор, третий - способ "перемотки" - от начала, от текущей позиции или от конца. А второй параметр указывает на сколько байт "перематывать". Также парная к ней функция ftell, которая возвращает текущее положение.

Если используете работу через stream (fstream), тогда нужна функция seekg.

Comment: А как отслеживать смещения? строки-то разной длины, скорее всего.

Comment: не знаю поэтому хочу более хороший способ если найдёшь напиши

Comment: Тогда какой смысл в ответе? :) Решение в общем случае — построчное чтение. Второй вариант — чтение большим буфером с отслеживанием позиций символов переводов строк. Конкретное решение зависит от конкретных требований, количества и частоты обращений, вида файла...